# Unable to mount an EFS volume on an ECS task definition container using Terraform

Tags: terraform, continuous-integration, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-efs

Using terraform, I am trying to attach an EFS volume to a container. I would specify a folder to mount on rather than the root path. I have tried everything but no matter what I do, the `root_directory` option seems to be ignored.

This is my task definition snippet:

```
resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "ecs_task_def" {
  family                = "application"
  container_definitions = jsonencode([
    {
      ...
    },
    {
      name : "redis",
      mountPoints = [
        {
          "readOnly" : null,
          "containerPath" : "/bitnami/redis/data",
          "sourceVolume" : "efs"
        }
      ],
      ...
    }
  ])
  ...

  volume {
    name = "efs"

    efs_volume_configuration {
      file_system_id     = var.ecs_efs_filesystem_id
      transit_encryption = "DISABLED"
      root_directory     = "/some/path/here"
      authorization_config {
        iam = "DISABLED"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

No matter what I try to do, the container always mounts on the at the root. I have tried creating the folders myself but nothing changes. No matter what I do, I always end up with this:

[image: every single time!]

I would appreciate it if someone could tell where I could be going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Have you enabled access to the EFS from your ECS security group?

Comment: @MarkoE if it's mounting, just with the wrong path, then it isn't an access issue.

Comment: Ah, ok, I misread the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ecs_task_definition):

> Directory within the Amazon EFS file system to mount as the root directory inside the host. If this parameter is omitted, the root of the Amazon EFS volume will be used. Specifying / will have the same effect as omitting this parameter. This argument is ignored when using `authorization_config`.

You are specifying `authorization_config` which means it is ignoring the `root_directory` setting. Since you aren't doing anything but disabling something that is already disabled by default inside the `authorization_config`  you should try just deleting the `authorization_config` entirely.

The `authorization_config` is for use with an EFS Access Point. If you were using an EFS Access Point you would specify the mount location in the Access Point settings, which is why Terraform is ignoring your current `root_directory` setting.

Comment: You, my sir @Mark B, are a genius. Thank you. That solved my issue and I am able to mount the correct folder. Thanks again!